# bash script simple operations

Tags: bash

I'm very very new to bash scripting and just wanted to have a little play around.

Ive created a file containing 2 IP addresses and 2 netmasks so far I've got the code to print the addresses and netmasks from that file and work out the addresses network number, I am just wanting to add more code which simply works out how many hosts are on that network and how many other networks share the same netmask.

I know how to do this on paper, pretty simple.

Very basic and I am aware, just want some simple pointers in bash.

Comment: Show some example code

Comment: Show us what your input and output should be and what your calculations are. Compared to the Windows cmd.exe shell, BASH is a powerhouse. However, Unix shells were mainly designed to run Unix commands, and aren't so great at calculations. It's probably possible to do what you want in pure BASH, but if you're doing something other than running various commands, you're better off using something like Python or Perl.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this using `ipcalc` in a [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) :

[image: ipcalc]